# recover the value above in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-partitioning

I want to recover the value above by name.

See the table.

[image]

I would like to have a result like in the column before last number_week.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the logic for calculating this column. How did you come up with those numbers? <edited> Oh wait... I got it. Would help in the future if you explain this since it's not terribly obvious (Need the previous week's week_number, or the current week if there was no previous week for the `name`).

Comment: I do not want to calculate.
Example: for this week, I would like to get the number of the past week.
number of the first week = 1 and the name = A so in the column before last number_week I put the value 1.
but the second the first week = 2 and the name = A so in the column before last number_week I put the value 1.
I'm sorry, I had a hard time explaining it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT number_week,
  name,
  LAG(number_week, 1, number_week) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY number_week) as before_last_number_week
FROM t1;
```

[sqlfiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84130/2)

This makes use of the `Lag()` Window Functions. A "Window" is a group of records that may optionally be ordered. Here we group up records by `Name` (so two groups/windows) and we order them by `week_number`. Then with `Lag()` we select the previously record's week_number (in that window). `Lag()` can take a default value, so we specify that the default is the current record's `week_number`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is nifty. I updated the answer. Thanks!!! I guess I should RTFM on that one.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.
It works perfectly.
thank you very much